# Discord.js RichEmbed field values "empty" even thought they are not. messageUpdate

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

So basically I have been making an log for message edit. The aim of the function is to write in modlog channel if someone edits the message. Also I wanted bot to write message before and after update.

**Here is the code:**

```
bot.on('messageUpdate', (oldMessage, newMessage) => {
    var msgup = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(`**MESSAGE EDIT**`)
    .addField(`Old Message:` , `${oldMessage.content}`)
    .addField(`New Message:` , `${newMessage.content}`)
    .addField(`In channel:` , oldMessage.channel)
    .addField(`By` , oldMessage.author)
    .setTimestamp()
    newMessage.channel.send(msgup).catch(console.error);

 });
```

**The console error :**

```
C:\Users\grofg\desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\RichEmbed.js:166
    if (!/\S/.test(value)) throw new RangeError('RichEmbed field values may not be empty.');
                           ^

RangeError: RichEmbed field values may not be empty.
    at RichEmbed.addField (C:\Users\grofg\desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\RichEmbed.js:166:34)
    at Client.bot.on (C:\Users\grofg\desktop\discordbot\index.js:455:6)
    at Client.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at MessageUpdateAction.handle (C:\Users\grofg\desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageUpdate.js:13:16)
    at MessageUpdateHandler.handle (C:\Users\grofg\desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageUpdate.js:7:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\grofg\desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\grofg\desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\grofg\desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\grofg\desktop\discordbot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
```

**What the bot does:**

-Bot executes the function exactly as planned. I have all components in embed (Title, 4xFields, and a timestamp). In all fields everything is written correctly (old message,new message, channel and author) But what happens?

-Even though bot does the function it stops with error. The bot crashes and it says Field is empty even though It writes everything and is not empty surely.

**What have i tried?**

Firstly, I tried removing content from both `oldMessage.content` and `newMessage.content`. It does the same thing anyways.

Secondly, I tried making it like `.addField('Old Message:' , oldMessage)` without `'${}'`.
Also I have tried doing the same thing but with `.content`. 
It still does the same thing, it does the job but makes an error and crash.

Because of console error:

`at Client.bot.on (C:\Users\grofg\desktop\discordbot\index.js:455:6)`
I tought it was problem at that embed because line 455 is exactly line with `.addField('Old Message:' , '${oldMessage.content}')`

***Thanks for reading through whole question and I would appreciate any kind of help or hint for solution of this problem.***

Sincerely,
    -Luke

Comment: And you're sure `oldMessage.content` isn't empty? If you `console.log(oldMessage)` as the first line what does it print?

Comment: I mean content in it is surely not empty because I get the Field filled with message before edit, and a message after edit. But still it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bot.on('messageUpdate', (oldMessage, newMessage) => {

if (oldMessage.author.bot) return;
if (oldMessage.content === newMessage.content) return;
if(!oldMessage.partial) {

var msgup = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setTitle(`**MESSAGE EDIT**`)
.addField(`Old Message:` , `${oldMessage.content.slice(0, 950)}\n\u200B`)
.addField(`New Message:` , `${newMessage.content.slice(0, 950)}\n\u200B`)
.addField(`In channel:` , oldMessage.channel.name)
.addField(`By` , oldMessage.author.tag)
.setTimestamp()
newMessage.channel.send(msgup).catch(console.error);
};    
});
```

I believe it is `oldMessage` that would be causing this. Here is what I have done, so it can't be empty. (Also added `.name` to your `message.channel` so it shows the name properly, same with `oldMessage.author`, I added `.tag`) Hopefully this helped.

Comment: Hey,

 I've tried using your advice and It didn't went the way I expected.

So basically after implementing this code you provided the bot does not crash. But he sends one embed properly as planned but continues to spam embeds that  have Old and New messages blank.

It spam sends it until I turn the bot  off.

Comment: Yea, sorry about that, added in a few checks that will stop that. Check out the code snippet above.